# Was the British Army a millionaire factory in the early 20th century?

Tags: military, british-empire, economy

I'm reading "Kenya Diary" by [Richard Meinertzhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Meinertzhagen) where he relates his experiences as a junior officer in the British army around 1902. At one point he states that during his 5 year service in East Africa he saved about 3000 pounds, because he had no expenses to speak of. I fed that figure into several inflation calculators and that comes to 350,000-400,000 pounds in today's money. If that's what the British army was paying its junior officers at the time it seems a military career would be a very reliable way of getting rich. AFAIK modern day soldiers are not very well paid so there are three options:

1. Meinertzhagen is mistaken/lying.
2. I got my economics wrong somehow (quite possible).
3. The British army was a *really* good place to be in around that time.

Which is it?

Comment: Was this 3000 solely from his soldier's pay or did he have outside investments?

Comment: Cursory googling indicates that you can probably scrub option (3).

Comment: Prior to the 1871 Cardwell Reforms, most officer commissions were [purchased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_of_commissions_in_the_British_Army).

Comment: £900 a year is about £75 per month, over 5 years with an historically low 5% rate of return compound interest would give you almost £5000 (according to https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php) so this doesn't seem unreasonable if he really had little to no expenses.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is officers. Those folks who actually fight the wars would be a very different matter.

Comment: We don't need to be focusing so much on salary ranges, but on benefits. If you could live a good life as a Major without needing to spend on housing, decent food, et cetera then his comments are quite reasonable. These days I believe that the provided benefits are of substantially lesser grade (relatively speaking) than they were historically, but maybe someone can chime in on that?

Comment: There's also option 4, which is a form of selection bias - believe it or not, there's a rather high incidence of people from wealthy and powerful families voluntarily serving in the military (for various reasons, probably the most significant being that a term of service in the military provides a good boost to future political ambitions).  Not saying this is the case here, but it's always worth considering which is the cause and which is the effect - in this case, does the military make people rich, or do rich people join the military?

Comment: "Saved £3000" presumably means "Didn't have to spend £3000 that he would have done if he'd been at home", not "Put £3000 of unspent salary in a savings account." As such, this is more of a question about Meinertzhagen's lifestyle when at home than about British Army pay.

Comment: @Bad_Bishop OK but that doesn't seem relevant, since Meinertzhagen wasn't born until 1878 and didn't enter the army until 1899.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. [Richard Meinertzhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Meinertzhagen) is known to be a serious liar. Refer to his Wikipedia article: for example, he stole numerous biological samples and presented them as his own in Europe.
2. That said, the Meinertzhagens were a wealthy family and there's no reason to presume the army salary was Richard's sole source of income.
3. According to [*The Meinertzhagen Mystery* by Brian Garfield](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1597974471), before his retirement in 1925 as a major, Meinertzhagen's salary was about **£900 yearly**. The Bank of England inflation calculator says it is equivalent to £52,016 in 2017. Coincidentally, that's almost identical to the second lowest step of the [current British army pay](http://www.armedforces.co.uk/armypayscales.php#.WrTi_KhuaUk) for a Major, £52,078.

So if anything, the British Army pay was a fair bit lower compared to today - by 1925, Meinertzhagen had been a Major for 10 years. The current pay for a Major, however, tops out at £60,381, some 16% more that his inflation adjusted £52,016.

Comment: Strange for someone to stay the same rank for 10 years in the military. Something is wrong there.

Comment: @corsiKa Up or Out is modern practice; but historically it was possible to spend a full working career as a junior officer/enlisted man.  That in turn heavily slowed down promotions all across the board.  Expediting them was a major factor in modern up or out policies.

Comment: @corsiKa reading his biography, it looks like he was given temporary (brevet) promotion during the war, but this would have lapsed at a later date. The dates are significant - after WWI, the Army was glutted with officers, and there was very little opportunity for promotion - it's not particularly surprising that his career then stalled.

Comment: (For context, Montgomery ended the war as a captain breveted to Major. Even with a period of active service and apparently good connections, he didn't get a substantive promotion until summer 1925)